# Warning:the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-module' is specified

Tags: kotlin

When I upgrade my Project Kotlin version from 1.0.5 to 1.1.1, it produce the warning

`Warning:the '-d' option with a directory destination is ignored because '-module' is specified` during compilation. What is this warning for? What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Kotlin bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14619) fixed in version 1.1.2.

Comment: Thanks. Is 1.1.2 Kotlin version out?

Comment: Will be out very soon.

Comment: I still see this warning when using 1.1.2-2. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/IjL1o